# How do you change the sorting of Laravel Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-notification

I am printing the notifications for a Model in Laravel 5:

```
@foreach ($booking->notifications as $notification)                     
        <div class="message">
            <div class="myMessage">
              <p>{{ $notification->data[0])}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>                      
@endforeach
```

These notifications are being printed in descending order, is there a way I can change this so they print in ascending order?

The [Laravel documentatio](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait)n states:

> By default, notifications will be sorted by the created_at timestamp

It's worth mentioning that there are multiple Notification classes that have been used with this model so I'm not sure if that affects the sorting behavior?

Comment: Can you show how you have your relation set up?

Comment: Yeah, it would be easier if we knew what the code in your controller looked like.

Comment: Why would you want to see the controller? It has nothing to do with the way notifications work in Laravel. If you have specified `use Notifiable;` in your model then Laravel automatically associates the model with any Notification records using the model->id

Comment: You should be doing all your code processing and data retrieval in the controller, not the view.

Comment: since you are receiving the notification as a collection, I think the cleanest way is to use collection functions to do any operation on the result.

Comment: @Derek There is no code processing going on, it's a simply control statement that is looping over a collection and printing the data. it's perfectly fine to keep presentation logic in the view, as long as it is 'presentation logic'.

Comment: @PeymanSeraj I don't follow, can you elaborate? Maybe with an example?

Comment: I am glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Peyman Seraj led me in the right direction here.

With Laravel collections you can use collection methods, so I used the [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby) method on my collection:

```
@foreach ($booking->notifications->sortBy('created_at') as $notification)
```

This now prints the data in ascending order.

Answer (score 6):

Just stump upon the issue:
by following the Notifiable trait i found the relation has order assigned to it.

You can override it in your model:

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->morphMany(\Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')->orderByRaw('-read_at','DESC')->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
}
```

in my case i was going for the unread first then the rest.
If you wanna set the sort on your query just use plain relation:

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->morphMany(\Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable');
}
```